# Need aid on Javascript dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick, toolbar, dropdown

So essentially I can't figure out why this menu won't dropdown when I click on the hamburger icon, any help will be greatly appreciated

```
Javascript:

function myFunction(){
    var hamburger=document.getElementById('nav-btn')
    var dropdownContent=document.getElementsByClassName('nav')


    hamburger.onclick=dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");

    //or hamburger.onclick=dropdownContent.style.display("block");
}   


CSS:
    #nav-btn {
    display: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1099px) {
    li {
      display: none;
    }

    #nav-btn {
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      bottom: 110px;
    }

    #nav-btn:hover {
        content: url('Menu.png');
    }


HTML:
<html>
<body>
    <span id="nav-btn"><image src="Menugreen.png" input type="button" onclick="myFunction()"/></span>
      <div class="nav">
       <ul>
          <li id="Programs"> <a href="Programs.html"> Programs </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="Tshirts.html"> T-Shirts </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="About.html"> About </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again I am just asking for advice on why the dropdown span id of nav-btn doesn't dropdown the content of ul everything else works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to toggle the `show` class, but don't have a `show` class defined. [`toggleClass()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is for adding or removing a CSS class by its name.

```js
// Get DOM references
var hamburger = document.getElementById('nav-btn')
var dropdownContent = document.querySelector('.nav')

// Set up event handler
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
 dropdownContent.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
#nav-btn {
 display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1099px) {
 .hide {
     display: none;
  }

  #nav-btn {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 110px;
  }

  /* Change the image when you hover over the image, not the span*/
  #nav-btn > img:hover {
   content: url('Menu.png');
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="nav-btn">
  <image src="Menugreen.png" alt="menu">
  <input type="button" value=" - - -">
</span>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="Programs"><a href="Programs.html">Programs</a></li>
    <li> <a href="Tshirts.html">T-Shirts</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="About.html">About</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for nav hover fix and the quick response! Unfortunately, this is still not working. When I ran your code snippet it worked but it isn't working on my end (I already checked for syntax errors). First why do I need the value=" - - -" (why does this appear I want the image to be the collapse button) and why did you replace li with .hide? Now the list is always visible. Thank you for going out of your way the first time to answer my question. Have a great day man!

Comment: I only added `value= ---` so that you could see something here since we don't have access t your images. Also, it's not entirely clear as to what you are doing, so my answer is meant to give you a working example of how to implement something like this. You made reference to a "show" class, but didn't actually have one.